# Is it possible to set conversation metadata for a conversation without replying back?

Tags: c#, botframework

In the Microsoft Bot Framework, it is possible to set conversation metadata on a reply message by using (documented on http://docs.botframework.com/connector/tracking-bot-state):

```
// Set a property on the BotUserData 
public static void SetBotUserData(this Message message, string property, object data)

// Set a property on the BotConversationData 
public static void SetBotConversationData(this Message message, string property, object data)

// Set a property on the BotPerUserInConversationData 
public static void SetBotPerUserInConversationData(this Message message, string property, object data)
```

However, it only works if a reply message is sent back. Is it possible to set state on a conversation without replying back to the message?

Answer (score 0):

It is. You will need the botId, the userId and a message. You can do the following:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
    var client = scope.Resolve<IConnectorClient>();

    var data = await client.Bots.GetUserDataAsync(botId, userId);

    data.SetProperty("key", "value");

    await client.Bots.SetUserDataAsync(botId, userId, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround.

Simply doing something along the lines of:

```
var reply = message.CreateReplyMessage(null);
reply.SetBotConversationData("MyData", myData);
return reply;
```

This works. The bot doesn't reply and a state gets set on the conversation. Not sure if this is a good way to this though.